# How to change an array element of a class module, which is item of a Dictionary?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, class, dictionary

**What I have:**

1. A Dictionary (sData).
2. All items in sData are instances of a class module (cls).
3. Each instance of the class module contains a 2D array (cls.arrAtt).
4. arrAtt is declared as public variant in the class module
5. Basic knowledge of VBA

**What I'm trying to do:**

Replace all "true" and "false" elements of the array with "Yes" and "No".

```
For Each key In sData
    Set cls = sData(key)
    For j = LBound(cls.arrAtt, 2) To UBound(cls.arrAtt, 2)
        If cls.arrAtt(1, j) = "true" Then cls.arrAtt(1, j) = "Yes"
        If cls.arrAtt(1, j) = "false" Then cls.arrAtt(1, j) = "No"
    Next j
Next key
```

[image]

(IF statements are triggered correctly)

As you can see in the picture, looping through the array does not change it's elements.

Any ideas why?

**Here is how the arrays are filled in:**

```
with sh1
    For i = 2 To .UsedRange.Rows.count
       If sData.Exists(.Cells(i, rCol).Value2) Then
           Set cls = sData(.Cells(i, rCol).Value2)
       Else
           Set cls = New cls_Source_Attributes
           sData.Add .Cells(i, rCol).Value2, cls
       End If
    
       cls.idRow = i
       cls.arrAtt = .Range("" & .Cells(i, firstCol).Address & ":" & .Cells(i, lastCol).Address & "")
    Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add a "method" to your class, like for instance

```
Public Sub arrAttChange(i As Long, j As Long, val As Variant)
    arrAtt(i, j) = val
End Sub
```

and then use it in your code like follows:

```
For Each key In sData
    Set cls = sData(key)
    For j = LBound(cls.arrAtt, 2) To UBound(cls.arrAtt, 2)
        If cls.arrAtt(1, j) = "true" Then cls.arrAttChange 1, j, "Yes"
        If cls.arrAtt(1, j) = "false" Then cls.arrAttChange 1, j, "No"
    Next
Next key
```

A enhancement of this code from the logical point of view could be

```
For Each key In sData
    Set cls = sData(key)
    With cls ' <-- reference the object

        For j = LBound(.arrAtt, 2) To UBound(.arrAtt, 2)
            Select Case .arrAtt(1, j)
                Case "true"
                    .arrAttChange 1, j, "Yes"

                Case "false"
                    .arrAttChange 1, j, "No"
            End Select
        Next

    End With
Next
```

---

Another possibility is using a "helper" array in the class "consumer" code while leaving the class code untouched

```
Dim arrAtt As Variant ' declare a "helper" array
For Each key In sData
    Set cls = sData(key)
    arrAtt = cls.arrAtt ' initialize the helper array with the values from the class one and change it in the following For - Next loop
    For j = LBound(arrAtt, 2) To UBound(arrAtt, 2)
        Select Case arrAtt(1, j)
            Case "true"
                arrAtt(1, j) = "Yes"

            Case "false"
                arrAtt(1, j) = "No"
        End Select
    Next
    cls.arrAtt = arrAtt ' assign the changed array back to the class array
Next
```

Comment: Sorry for my late feedback. Thank you for your fast answer and advices too. Can you please explain to me why it works that way, and not the way I tried? And why cls.arrAtt=arrAtt works (last row), and cls.arrAtt(1,j)= "No" doesn't? I thought it's the same thing.

Comment: @HYs, I addmittedly don't know the real deep reason of that, but my guessing is that that `Public` member of `Variant` type can be assigned as a "whole" only, like you yourself are doing with `cls.arrAtt = .Range("" & .Cells(i, firstCol).Address & ":" & .Cells(i, lastCol).Address & "")`. While it can be queried in its "details"